# How do I remove TextMate's temporary files using rm?

Tags: textmate, rm

Note that I'm not trying to disable the creation of these files.  I want to keep them around *until* I'm ready to commit changes to my source control.

The files are scattered throughout many subdirectories of the main source code directory and are of the format "._".  For example, test.txt becomes ._test.txt.

I've tried this command, but it doesn't work:

```
rm -rf ._*
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

GNU find has a `-delete` option.  If you have GNU find, this should work (and it should be immune to any problems with whitespace and other funny characters in file names):

```
find . -name '._*' -delete
```

From the documentation (`info find`):

```
-- Action: -delete
    Delete files or directories; true if removal succeeded.  If the
    removal failed, an error message is issued.

    The use of the `-delete' action on the command line automatically
    turns on the `-depth' option (*note find Expressions::).  This can
    be surprising if you were previously just testing with `-print',
    so it is usually best to remember to use `-depth' explicitly.

    If `-delete' fails, `find''s exit status will be nonzero (when it
    eventually exits).
```

Comment: OS X doesn't ship with GNU find though.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to use this instead:

```
find . -name "._*" -exec rm {} \;
```

However, I'd love to hear if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Using `find` and `xargs` is a bit tricky. Read the find manual that says: "However, you may wish to consider the `-print0` primary in conjunction with `xargs -0`".

Comment: Using `{}` in this way will cause serious errors with files having names with embedded whitespace.  Almost always correct to us `'{}'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

While deleting them isn't particularly harmful, it'd be good to be sure you know what you're discarding since [those are in fact neither temporary files nor unique to TextMate](https://superuser.com/questions/11026/textmate-creates-temporary-files-and-doesnt-delete-them).